# LWC Combobox Options Styling

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a combobox in my LWC which I'd like to remove the space and the checkmark from the options. Could you please if/how I can apply the styling in CSS?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to apply custom styling you will need to create a custom combobox component. See the [Lightning Design System combobox component blueprint](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/combobox/#%22Input%22-markup) for inspiration.